# Storing Database with a uniqure key number Firebase

Tags: forms, firebase, file, dart, flutter

The code takes input from user in a form and submit  it to Firebase cloud.But it stores the form data with a random unique key order.can't we store those forms in a key order rather then some random values id?

```
   Edit 1: random values id like the one in the image.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwnVP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible (all records should have a unique key), the way to resolve that issue is storing an additional field (for instance "order") and then fetch data in the need order.